# Throttling Search with UISearchController

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an Xamarin.iOS app which does some search on a long list that takes some time.I would like to introduce some throttling instead of searching for every single key stroke . Any idea ?

Comment: Usual approach is to wait for a minimum number of key presses. This is very useful when you are about to hammer an API service!  You can also introduce some caching incase they hit delete or re-enter the same key.

Comment: Start a timer when a key is typed. If another key is typed, restart the timer. When the timer fires, perform the search

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Reactive extensions, asuming that you use C# style events instead of iOS Delegates.

Here is a bare bone sample code with UITextView:

```
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>
(
   //Those are actions used to subscribe and unsubscribe for the event
   eventHandler => TextView.Changed += eventHandler,
   eventHandler => TextView.Changed -= eventHandler
) 
.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))  //This will sample every 500 to check if the event has been raised
.Select(e => e.Sender as UITextView) //This is used so we can directly use  the TextView in the subscribe method


observable.Subscribe(textView =>
{
    //This will be executed if the event was raised the last 500 miliseconds
    //This may not run on the UI thread
    InvokeOnMainThread(() => Label.Text = textView.Text);
});
```

This will Sample the text every 500 miliseconds and if the event was rased at least once it will call the Action in the Subscribe method. Or you can use .Throttle instead of .Sample which will be called if the event was not raised for the interval which will be 500 miliseconds after the user stopped typing.

The cool thing is that you can filter the text with a:

```
  .Where(textView => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textView.Text) || !IsCompleteNonSense(textView.Text));
```

after the Select method so it wont raise the event if the text is empty or if you want to make some other checks.

I came across this watching a presentation from Xamarin Evolve 2016 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYEbUF4xs1Q) is a link to the video. And [here](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Reactive-Examples) is a link to the source code.

The samples are on Xamarin.Forms but they will give you a good starting point.

Comment: I do like a lot this one, but I am not using Rx (I was more looking at the basic now).

Comment: In this case I would use NSTmer to sample the text at regular intervals, perform some checks if search is necessary then search.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, they are both answering and valuable . Will go for NSTimer for now , but have no doubt investing in Rx will worth it.